# Cant copy value between two functions

Tags: c++, syntax

So here is my code:

```
void Draw() {
        int x = 57;
        int y = 500;
        int temp = x;
        int colour;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 13; ++i){
            for (int j = 0; j <= 9; ++j){
                if (i % 2 == 0){
                    colour = 3;
                    }
                else colour = 4;
                DrawRectangle(x, y, 67, 30, colors[colour]);
                x = x + 67;
            }
            y = y - 30;
            x = temp;
        }


        DrawCircle(100, 100, 10, colors[2]);
        DrawRectangle(20, 0, 95, 12, colors[1]);


    }

    void Move(int key, int x, int y) {
        if (key == GLUT_KEY_LEFT) { // left arrow key is pressed

        }
        else if (key == GLUT_KEY_RIGHT) { // right arrow key is pressed


        }
        glutPostRedisplay(); // Redo- the drawing by calling
    }
```

These are my two functions in a class. I need to copy the values of x and y from Move() to Draw(), but Draw() does not take any arguments, What other way is there to do this. Also, if someone needs the full code he can ask for it.

Comment: `x` and `y` should probably be instance variables?

Answer (score 2):

### Option 1

You could just change the function signature to `Draw(int x, int y)`. While you haven't stated you cannot change the function signature, I'm guessing this option isn't possible.

### Option 2

You stated these are member functions of a class. Therefore you need to increase the scope of the variables beyond the `Move` function. You can achieve this by making them member variables. For example:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() :
        mX(0),
        mY(0)
    {
        // Do nothing
    }

    void Draw()
    {
        ... code in here that uses mX and mY ...
    }

    void Move(int key, int x, int y)
    {
        mX = x;
        mY = y;

        ... other code ...
    }

private:
    // Class member variables accessible by all functions in the class
    int mX;
    int mY;
};
```

Comment: This works! You don't know how much grateful I am to you. I had been working on this for quite a long time, and could not think of this. Thank You +rep

Answer (score 0):

You can either use global variables or send values as arguements. Global variables are declared outside the body of any function.

Comment: Yes it works with global variables. But our Instructor has strictly restricted using them. I also tried passing them as arguments, but the values always get overwritten as the Draw() function is called from various locations.

Comment: Yes each time the values as arguments are passed previous will be overwriiten. Consider saving the value of draw function each time it is called. If possible can u elaborate what u r tryingto do fully??

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand why you don't pass arguments to the `Draw()` function since you need to pass variables to it. But here is another way to do this instead of using global variables.

You could create a new class which has these two method maybe name it as `Pen`? Then you add two property to the `Pen` class, you change the value in function `Move()`, then `Draw()` could use those variables.

This is better than using global variables, because you only want to use them within these two functions right? It's better to keep every variable in the scope that they should be.

Hope this would help.

Comment: How would I be able to access the members of the function Move() from my new Pen class?

Comment: You could move them into Pen class.